# Combinatorial Optimization problems on Docker or AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, or-tools

I am attacking a combinatorial optimization problem similar to the multi-knapsack problem.  The problem has an optimal solution, and i prefer not to settle for an approximate solution.

Are there any recommended tutorials regarding the quick prototyping and deployment of combinatorial optimization solutions (for senior software engineers that are also Big Data newbies)?  I want to move quickly from prototype to deployment onto a docker cluster or AWS.

My background is in distributed systems (a focus on .NET, java, kafka, docker containers, etc...), thus I'm typically inclined to solve complex problems by parallel processing across a cluster of machines (via scaling on a docker cluster or AWS). However, this particular problem can NOT be solved in a brute force manner as the problem space is too large (roughly 100^1000 combinations are possible).

I've limited experience with “big data”, but I'm studying up on knapsack solvers, genetic algorithms, reinforcement learning, and some other AI/ML approaches.  Given my limited exposure in this area, how would one recommend I tackle a problem such as this?

1. I tend to favor the approach of leveraging existing frameworks/libraries as much as possible.  Good idea?  Or would one recommend using Accord.Net or ML.Net or some other library to build a custom model?
2. If existing frameworks are the way to go, any particular favorites?  tensorflow? Any thoughts on Google OR tools: https://developers.google.com/optimization/    Anything in the AWS space?
3. Any good tutorials, videos, or podcasts that can get me prototyping quickly? (keeping in mind my goal of deploying and validating the model on a docker cluster)

Thank you for any help and guidance!

Comment: This may be of interest to you: https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow

Comment: I would start with looking at a MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) formulation. MIP solvers are readily available, and can solve different type of knapsack problems, usually quite efficiently. In addition, this will give you guaranteed optimal solutions. Heuristics (as suggested below) are not doing that, so they are probably not what you want.

Comment: thank you!  i'll definitely have a look at MIP

Answer (score 1):

The [Cloud Balancing problem](https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/useCases/cloudOptimization.html) in OptaPlanner (open source, java) is a multi-knapsack problem. There's a tutorial for it in the user guide. Many users run OptaPlanner implementations on Docker (normal open JDK 8 image) and AWS. [Here's an Employee Rostering implementation](https://github.com/kiegroup/optashift-employee-rostering) that is deployed to OpenShift Dedicated (which generates an docker image that it runs on AWS) - it exposes a REST api (which is Swagger documented even).

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. If you are changing a wheel on your car you would use a car jack and wheel wrench. If you are decorating your house you would probably use brushes and paint rollers. If you have an *optimisation* problem, then use an *optimiser*. All the big optimisers have support for multiple APIs, and can deploy to AWS or similar. If you want a true optimal solution rather than near-optimal, then heuristics like GA etc are probably not good enough. Not sure that AI and ML techniques are more than marginally relevant; a bit like trying to change a car wheel with a paintbrush!

Comment: Sorry if that seems a bit abrupt; probably written too quickly and posted. Not criticising Geoffrey at all - I totally agree with his approach. Look also at the big commercial optimisers (CPLEX, Gurobi, XPress) and the cheaper or open source solvers like SCIP. If you have a properly hard combinatoric problem then look also at constraint programming approaches, but be aware that big combinatoric problems may be extremely hard to solve to optimality even with the best solvers; in which case you may have to fall back on heuristics, so look at e.g. column generation which is a strong method.

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick OptaPlanner is one of the big optimisers in the fortune 500 / government / startup world. It's a small, unknown one in the academic world though, which might explain why some still think it's just another open source hobby implementation. That was 10 years ago the case, not any more. The main difference of it using metaheuristics and other heuristics instead of linear programming or constraint programming is that it scales up better (dataset size + memory/cpu size) but scales down worse (only dataset size, not memory/cpu size - it runs on android too).

Comment: +1 on AI/ML techniques are [the wrong tool for an optimization job](https://twitter.com/GeoffreyDeSmet/status/894650444428918785). Scientific papers show that they are consistently inferior to basic constraint solving algorithms.

Comment: Definitely not trying to put down OptaPlanner. It is **clearly** a very good tool with a decade or more of R&D behind it. Not *fashionable* as it uses different approaches to many others. But I think that is a **good** thing that somebody explores these algorithms and exploits them. Too many people are hung up on the apparent 'defects' of heuristics without seeing the many advantages. Naive implementations can be brittle and offer uneven performance. Not enough people put the effort into refining their implementations and properly engineering and testing their stuff.

Comment: Thanks all!  appreciate the insight. it's a good start to attacking the problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your insight above.  I’m having a look at optaplanner and google-OT, as well as a few other solvers.

To follow up on this question, if I were to relax the constraint that I want the optimal answer , and allow for “approximate” solutions , would this change your guidance or recommended tool set (libraries/frameworks) in any way?